# NextJs Link does full reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

My Links in my next's app do a full reload. Why is this happening?

```
const navigation = [
  { name: 'Immobilien', href: '/real-estates', icon: FolderIcon, current: false },
  { name: 'Documents', href: '/documents', icon: InboxIcon, current: false },
  { name: 'Exports', href: '/exports', icon: ChartBarIcon, current: false },
]

    {navigation.map((item) => (
      <Link
        key={item.name}
        href={item.href}
        aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
      >
        <a>
          <item.icon
            aria-hidden="true"
          />
          {item.name}
        </a>
      </Link>
    ))}
```

I tried to do it with a tags swell previous but that had the same effect.

Comment: Maybe you find an answer here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9382

Comment: What does your `pages` folder structure look like?

Comment: Have you created/modified files like _app.js , _document.js , server.js? Also, are you using ISR/SSR?